# Multi-bar chart in angular

Tags: angular

Hi I am using NVD3 to design multibar chart.
https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/multiBarChart
[image: Please find the below image.]

How can I remove the decimal value from y-axis it is displaying as 1000.0 but I want to show only 1000.

How to bring the submitted and unsbmitted below the graph form Top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below `tickFormat` removes decimals but keeps thousands separator (see [d3.format](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-format)).

```
yAxis: {
  ...
  tickFormat: d => d3.format(',.0f')(d)
}
```

Comment: How to move the submitted and unsubmitted labels below the graph from top.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `tickFormat` function in `yAxis` property as mentioned in [documentation example](https://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart).

```
        yAxis: {
            axisLabel: 'Voltage (v)',
            tickFormat: function(d){
                return d3.format('')(d);
            },
        },
```

And in `format` function pass empty string. See more example about format function [here](http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e)

[Plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/qOXV6kbykc8v7QfZHm6n?p=preview).

Comment: How to move the submitted and un-submitted labels below the graph from top.